# Why do I need to reset user mapping always after restoring my DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore, logins

I have created a user using SQL Server 2014 management studio, I have mapped user to a couple of tables as db_owner. But after restoring my databases the mapping again cleared for the user and I need to set the User Mapping. How to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Is there any policy getting pushed, or any post restart script running which is removing this privilege. Can you see errorlog and look for any such script running

Comment: What do you mean by "mapped to a couple of tables?  Is the user in the `db_owner` role?  Or do you mean the user is associated with the `dbo` schema in some way?  How?

Comment: @MichaelGreen see the added screenshot

Comment: @Shanky how to check this policy getting pushed?

Comment: @FarazShuja You need to speak to AD team for that. Did you checked SQL server errorlog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix. I need to set my user as sysadmin then it does not get cleared user mappings after a db is restored.

Comment: I would disagree on this fix. sysadmin is the highest privilege account that can do whatever it wants. You should have a script to map the user to appropriate role post restore.